# Deselect text in RichTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a `RichTextBox` with a search box under it. I use the following code for the search functionality:

```
TabPage activePage = tabs.SelectedTab;
            RichTextBox xmlBox = activePage.Controls.Find("xmlBox", true).Single() as RichTextBox;

xmlBox.DeselectAll();

int index = 0;
int len = xmlBox.TextLength;
int lastIndex = xmlBox.Text.LastIndexOf(tbSearch.Text);

while (index < lastIndex)
{
     xmlBox.Find(tbSearch.Text, index, len, RichTextBoxFinds.WholeWord);
     xmlBox.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
     index = xmlBox.Text.IndexOf(tbSearch.Text, index) + 1;
}
```

What I want is that lets say a user types the word `User`. When he types the `U` I want all the `U`s to be highlighted, etc. and then if he deletes the `r` I want only `Use` to be highlighted. I was thinking that `DeselectAll()` would do the trick, but this isn`t working. Any other way to do this?

Comment: DeselectAll() will simply unselect any current selection.  Your code actually changed the BackColor() of previous text so you'd have to undo this...possibly be selecting everything and resetting it to the default color before again highlighting the new search value.

Comment: @Idle_Mind - Yep. That is what I ended up doing. Care to post this as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DeselectAll() will simply unselect any current selection. Your code actually changed the BackColor() of previous text so you'd have to undo this...possibly by selecting everything and resetting it to the default color before again highlighting the new search value.

Comment: Yep. I used `SelectAll()` then set the `BackColor` back to white. Thanks.